# make emacs (evil) auto-save on buffer change

Tags: emacs, evil

I'm using https://github.com/907th/vim-auto-save on vim. Giving emacs a try. Is there a way I can replicate vim-auto-save functionality in emacs?

I got (auto-save-visited-mode) enabled but it's only saving at some intervals. I want saves whenever I modify the buffer (ether by issuing commands in normmal mode or when leaving insert mode).